# How to use autocomplete box using angular js with bulky Data?

Tags: angularjs

i want to implement a auto complete text box ,I am new to angular.js ,From sources i got to know that in angular.js first we have to load whole data from database then search begins on that data.In my project i have to run search over 50000 records(database) hence its impossible to load 50000 thousand because of performance issue.

Is it possible to change data for search according to value typed in text box while searching ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are lookin for is Typehead. It is very easy to implement in Angular using Bootstrap UI.

[Typehead in Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Comment: can we change the dataset used for search at runtime on the basis input field value ?

Comment: Read about creating Anguar.js docs and about the typehead component itself.

Comment: thanks a lot, yeah i have read it and got the idea for implementing it . Can you please tell me what the advantages of using this instead of jquery auto complete .